# Interpretation of fixed effects logistic regression coefficients with a binary dependent variable

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

I have a question about interpreting logistic coefficient estimates with a binary dependent variable and fixed effects. In particular, I am focused on cases where each fixed effect group has only two observations. For example, consider a medical trial where subject participants are measured before and after treatment and the dependent variable is binary -- well or unwell. In this case, you can include subject fixed effects to control for non-treatment related subject heterogeneity.

However, when running this kind of regression, the logistic regression will omit any subject with non-dichotomous dependent variable observations. For example, it will omit data from all subjects who were observed {well, well} and {unwell, unwell} and only include subjects who were observed {well, unwell} or {unwell, well}.

The issue I'm having is in coefficient interpretation: in a logistic regression without fixed effects, I convert coefficients and interpret them as a change in log-odds. However, because including fixed effects induces non-dichotomous data to be dropped, it seems like these coefficients are "conditional on having a dichotomous outcome." This seems like an important difference: surely, the odds of being "well" among this dichotomous group is different than in the full sample (especially in cases where, say, only 25% of people are well). I'm not sure how to interpret log-odds, conditional on dichotomous outcomes...?

Not sure if I'm thinking about this totally incorrectly, would love any insight or sources.